# java id3tag duplicate mp3 files

Tags: java, id3

i work with the jid3tag librairy to modify metadata of mp3 files.
when i save my modification, it duplicate the mp3 file creating a "songtitle.mp3" and a "songtitle.original.mp3" .
my question is : how to modify a mp3 file without duplicate it?

here is my code:

```
TagOptionSingleton.getInstance().setDefaultSaveMode(TagConstant.MP3_FILE_SAVE_OVERWRITE);
    AbstractID3v2 id3v2= new ID3v2_4();
    // setup id3v2
    AbstractID3v2Frame frame;
    AbstractID3v2FrameBody frameBody;

    frameBody = new FrameBodyTIT2((byte) 0, "songTitle");
    frame = new ID3v2_4Frame(frameBody);
    ((AbstractFrameBodyTextInformation) frame.getBody()).setText(metatitle);
    id3v2.setFrame(frame);
    mp3file.setID3v2Tag(id3v2);
    try {
        mp3file.save();

        } catch (IOException | TagException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

thanks

Comment: It`s the default behavior of Mp3File.save(). Try passing the original file name to save: Mp3File.save("songtitle.mp3")

Comment: Thanks, i tried but it still duplicate the file.i also tried with mp3file.save("songtitle.mp3",tagconstant.mp3_file_save_overwrite); still doesnt work

Comment: Try this `mp3file.save(TagConstants.MP3_FILE_SAVE_OVERWRITE)`

This method: https://github.com/AngeloDias/ComuniPro/blob/7c9fb3fe81bdf96ab202db22075db4ade92fc916/Projeto/src/org/farng/mp3/MP3File.java#L859

Comment: yes i tried already, but the file is stil duplicated

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, i didnt find solution.

so i just delete the file using Files class like this:

```
 try {
        mp3file.save(TagConstant.MP3_FILE_SAVE_OVERWRITE);
        String p = destFile.getPath();
        String[] s = p.split(".mp3");
        Path path = Paths.get(s[0]+".original.mp3");
        System.out.println(path);
        Files.deleteIfExists(path);

        } catch (IOException | TagException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```